# Micro-PC as USB NAS

Tags: nas, freenas

I am thinking of trying a Micro-PC such as MK802 III as a USB NAS.

Is that a good idea?

Do USB hubs generally work with Micro-PCs?

I do need a LAN port, and I see many of these do not have it.  (With the MK802 there is an adapter I can buy).

I am thinking of one of the Open Source NAS frameworks.

Comment: Upvoted for neat idea. There's an Amazon review [here](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3S3LHUUIURKXH/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00A0I4YJK&nodeID=172282&store=electronics) which speaks of successfully using USB hard disks via a USB hub with the MK802 III, so I would expect that to work pretty well with FreeNAS or similar; the tricky part looks to be getting FreeNAS or similar onto the device, about which I haven't found much information. (Yet, at least -- I expect I'll be doing this myself if it works, so please update the question once you know!)

Comment: It confirms that a USB hub can be used :-)

Comment: Is this simply for a fun project? The MK802 III does not have a physical NIC; you're going to be relying on WiFi to access your files which will be terribly slow. USB External HDDs and USB Hubs generally don't mix; bogs things down (even single-disk access) quite a bit. You'd be much better off building a cheap NAS out of "real" hardware.

Comment: Agree with Rain. I was going to post the same thing. I think the performance on this will be really bad.

Answer (score 0):

This device is no high-speed ports ... except one HDMI ... Performance USB ports on this device does not exceed the capacity of 1 (one) HDD ... 5400 rpm. But if you had an external RAID controller + high-speed port that worked with the data, but rather several types of ports amd lightning bolt, it would be the thing.

> What kind of USB Ethernet adapter do you use ? I’ve tried with a basic
>   adatper and I’ve got the same poor performance. After i bought an
>   adapter with the same chipset as the Apple Adapter i reach 11 MB/s

HDD 5400 rpm ~ 30-70 MB/s ...

[How to turn a MK-802 mini Android device into a personal NAS on Steroids](http://onestepfurther.net/?p=205)

[image: MK-802]

If you do implement this, I would like to know the capacity of the resulting NAS, thx.